# Black Screen after logging in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: ubuntu, desktop

I was updating my Ubuntu 17.10 using the command `apt-get update`, which went perfectly fine but then after `upgrading` by using the command `apt-get upgrade`, my screen got all blank. I cannot see any icons or icon bar but hovering the mouse over icons shows the icon names, but don't show anything after opening the programs.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

The lock screen works perfectly fine. But after logging in the screen goes black.

Comment: Version 17.10 is an odd release to install now.  It was an interim release from 2017 for which support ended a year ago.  Any particular reason for installing that version?

Comment: I was using the version from the last one year, and I just ( don't exactly know why) didn't update to the latest version. But there are some important files which I can't afford to loose. I don't have any clue how can I resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

V17.10 was the last of two interim releases in that series, and support for it ended a year ago.  It's hard to know exactly what happened to your system, but it looks like attempting to upgrade it resulted in some corruption.

The good news is that apt only deals with packages.  So while your system isn't very functional, your personal files (the Home directory tree) should be unaffected.  Fixing things from here would be in two steps: save your files and do a fresh Ubuntu install with the current version.

**Saving your files**

To install a fresh version of Ubuntu, you will need to create a live session on a flash drive or DVD (create that on a working computer).  If you still have the media from when you first installed Ubuntu, that should still work and enable you to use a live session on this hosed computer to create media for the current release and to save your files.

From the live session, copy either the entire Home directory, or if you have limited external space, be selective and copy just the specific subdirectories and files you need.  If you have been making routine backups, you can just update that to ensure it's current.

If you put your Home directory on a separate partition when you originally installed Ubuntu, the backup will be a safety net, but you can reuse the Home partition with the new installation.  You can even recreate this if you didn't set it up that way originally if you don't mind getting some Linux grease under your fingernails.  The gist of how to reuse you Home partition or directory is covered in https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/upgrade-switch-linux-distros-without-losing-files/.

If you have a current backup of the Home directory, an alternative would be to restore it to the new installation.

Note that in either case, there's always the possibility that you may need to do a little cleanup if odds and ends of old package customization files aren't compatible with what's in the new installation.

**Installing Ubuntu**

The interim releases have a very short support life and aren't extensively tested.  They serve as a test bed for what will go into the next LTS release.  There typically isn't a good reason to use them unless you're a developer and need to test your product early.  Most users will fare better sticking to the stable, LTS releases.  There are fewer bugs, and upgrades are well provided for, so you aren't likely to encounter this problem again.  Install version 18.04, the current LTS release, with the desktop environment of your choice.  You can download the iso and create the media using whatever live session you have.

If any part of this process is new to you and the help you find online isn't adequate, post a new question with the specific issue.  That will keep everything from getting too broad for the intended scope of questions on the site.

Comment: I was thinking of installing Ubuntu 19.04. Is the version stable or should I install 19.04 as for now ?

Comment: @kunal, 19.04 is another interim release.  I wouldn't recommend it, and unless you have a specific need for it, there's no real benefit, only drawbacks.  The LTS releases are the stable releases, so 18.04 is the latest stable release.